# How do I process enum/struct/field attributes in a procedural macro?

Tags: rust

Serde supports applying custom attributes that are used with `#[derive(Serialize)]`:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Resource {
    // Always serialized.
    name: String,

    // Never serialized.
    #[serde(skip_serializing)]
    hash: String,

    // Use a method to decide whether the field should be skipped.
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Map::is_empty")]
    metadata: Map<String, String>,
}
```

I understand how to implement a procedural macro (`Serialize` in this example) but what should I do to implement `#[serde(skip_serializing)]`? I was unable to find this information anywhere. The [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/procedural-macros.html) don't even mention this. I have tried to look at the `serde-derive` source code but it is very complicated for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You implement attributes on fields as part of the derive macro for the struct (you can only implement derive macros for structs and enums).

Serde does this by checking every field for an attribute within the structures provided by `syn` and changing the code generation accordingly.

You can find the relevant code here: https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/master/serde_derive/src/internals/attr.rs

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of how to do this please? I see the code you mentioned but there is a lot of stuff also implemented.

Comment: If you are using `syn`, then you can access the fields' attributes by accessing the `attr` field of the `Field` struct. You obtain the `Field` struct by checking the `syn::MacroInput`'s `body` field for the [`Struct` variant](https://dtolnay.github.io/syn/syn/enum.Body.html) and then calling the [`fields` method](https://dtolnay.github.io/syn/syn/enum.VariantData.html#method.fields) to obtain the list of `Field`s

Answer (score 34):

1. First you must register all of your attributes in the same place you register your procedural macro. Let's say we want to add two attributes (we still don't talk what will they belong to: structs or fields or both of them):

   ```
    #[proc_macro_derive(FiniteStateMachine, attributes(state_transitions, state_change))]
    pub fn fxsm(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
        // ...
    }
   ```

   After that you may already compile your user code with the following:

   ```
    #[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, FiniteStateMachine)]
    #[state_change(GameEvent, change_condition)] // optional
    enum GameState {
        #[state_transitions(NeedServer, Ready)]
        Prepare { players: u8 },
        #[state_transitions(Prepare, Ready)]
        NeedServer,
        #[state_transitions(Prepare)]
        Ready,
    }
   ```

   Without that compiler will give a error with message like:

   > `state_change` does not belong to any known attribute.

   These attributes are optional and all we have done is allow them to be to specified. When you derive your procedural macro you may check for everything you want (including attributes existence) and `panic!` on some condition with meaningful message which will be told by the compiler.
2. Now we will talk about handling the attribute! Let's forget about `state_transitions` attribute because it's handling will not vary too much from handling struct/enum attributes (actually it is only a little bit more code) and talk about `state_change`. The `syn` crate gives you all the needed information about definitions (but not implementations unfortunately (I am talking about `impl` here) but this is enough for handling attributes of course). To be more detailed, we need [`syn::DeriveInput`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.16/syn/struct.DeriveInput.html), [`syn::Body`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.16/syn/enum.Body.html), [`syn::Variant`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.16/syn/struct.Variant.html), `syn::Attribute` and finally [`syn::MetaItem`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.16/syn/enum.MetaItem.html).

To handle the attribute of a field you need to go through all these structures from one to another. When you reach `Vec<syn:: Attribute>` - this is what you want, a list of all attributes of a field. Here our `state_transitions` can be found. When you find it, you may want to get its content and this can be done by using matching `syn::MetaItem` enum. Just read the docs :) Here is a simple example code which panics when we find `state_change` attribute on some field plus it checks does our target entity derive `Copy` or `Clone` or neither of them:

```
    #[proc_macro_derive(FiniteStateMachine, attributes(state_transitions, state_change))]
    pub fn fxsm(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
        // Construct a string representation of the type definition
        let s = input.to_string();

        // Parse the string representation
        let ast = syn::parse_derive_input(&s).unwrap();

        // Build the impl
        let gen = impl_fsm(&ast);

        // Return the generated impl
        gen.parse().unwrap()
    }

    fn impl_fsm(ast: &syn::DeriveInput) -> Tokens {
        const STATE_CHANGE_ATTR_NAME: &'static str = "state_change";

        if let syn::Body::Enum(ref variants) = ast.body {

            // Looks for state_change attriute (our attribute)
            if let Some(ref a) = ast.attrs.iter().find(|a| a.name() == STATE_CHANGE_ATTR_NAME) {
                if let syn::MetaItem::List(_, ref nested) = a.value {
                    panic!("Found our attribute with contents: {:?}", nested);
                }
            }

            // Looks for derive impls (not our attribute)
            if let Some(ref a) = ast.attrs.iter().find(|a| a.name() == "derive") {
                if let syn::MetaItem::List(_, ref nested) = a.value {
                    if derives(nested, "Copy") {
                        return gen_for_copyable(&ast.ident, &variants, &ast.generics);
                    } else if derives(nested, "Clone") {
                        return gen_for_clonable(&ast.ident, &variants, &ast.generics);
                    } else {
                        panic!("Unable to produce Finite State Machine code on a enum which does not drive Copy nor Clone traits.");
                    }
                } else {
                    panic!("Unable to produce Finite State Machine code on a enum which does not drive Copy nor Clone traits.");
                }
            } else {
                panic!("How have you been able to call me without derive!?!?");
            }
        } else {
            panic!("Finite State Machine must be derived on a enum.");
        }
    }

    fn derives(nested: &[syn::NestedMetaItem], trait_name: &str) -> bool {
        nested.iter().find(|n| {
            if let syn::NestedMetaItem::MetaItem(ref mt) = **n {
                if let syn::MetaItem::Word(ref id) = *mt {
                    return id == trait_name;
                }
                return false
            }
            false
        }).is_some()
    }
```

You may be interested in **reading** [serde_codegen_internals](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/tree/master/serde_derive/src/internals), [serde_derive](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/master/serde_derive), [serenity's `#[command]` attr](https://github.com/serenity-rs/serenity/blob/current/command_attr), [another small project of mine - `unique-type-id`](https://github.com/vityafx/unique-type-id), [fxsm-derive](https://github.com/vityafx/fxsm/tree/master/fxsm-derive). The last link is actually my own project to explain to myself how to use  procedural macros in Rust.

---

After some Rust 1.15 and updating the syn crate, it is no longer possible to check derives of a `enums/structs`, however, everything else works okay.

Comment: The `serde_codegen_internals` link is invalid now. Not sure where it is intended to point otherwise would have made the edit. Also, thanks for the answer, super helpful :).

Comment: @Mihir I've just updated the link to point to something which resembles what it was pointing to earlier. As far as I can remember, I was referring to the serde's code where they are handling procedural macros, and this new link points to their new home. Since the time of this answer, the project has greatly evolved and so earlier it was much easier to read and understand their code, but now it is a huge chunk of code and might not be that good as a starter's reading. I believe, there are good examples out there still. I'll try adding links to what I can find as well just in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

To expand Victor Polevoy's answer when it comes to the `state_transitions` attribute. I'm providing an example of how to extract the field attribute `#[state_transitions(NeedServer, Ready)]` on a enum that derives `#[derive(FiniteStateMachine)]`:

```
#[derive(FiniteStateMachine)]
enum GameState {
    #[state_transitions(NeedServer, Ready)] // <-- extract this
    Prepare { players: u8 },
    
    #[state_transitions(Prepare, Ready)]
    NeedServer,
   
    #[state_transitions(Prepare)]
    Ready,
}
```

```rust
use proc_macro::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro_derive(FiniteStateMachine, attributes(state_transitions))]
pub fn finite_state_machine(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {

    let ast = syn::parse(input).unwrap();

    // Extract the enum variants
    let variants: Vec<&syn::Variant> = match &ast.data {
        syn::Data::Enum(ref data_enum) => data_enum.variants.iter().collect(),
        other => panic!("#[derive(FiniteStateMachine)] expects enum, got {:#?}", other)
    };

    // For each variant, extract the attributes
    let _ = variants.iter().map(|variant| { 
        let attrs = variant.attrs.iter()
            // checks attribute named "state_transitions(...)"
            .find_map(|attr| match attr.path.is_ident("state_transitions") {
                true => Some(&attr.tokens),
                false => None,
            })
            .expect("#[derive(FiniteStateMachine)] expects attribute macros #[state_transitions(...)] on each variant, found none");

        // outputs: attr: "(NeedServer, Ready)"
        eprintln!("attr: {:#?}", attrs.to_string());

        // do something with the extracted attributes
        ...
    })
    .collect();

    ...
}
```

The content of the extracted `attrs` (typed `TokenStream`) looks like this:

```
TokenStream [
    Group {
        delimiter: Parenthesis,
        stream: TokenStream [
            Ident {
                ident: "NeedServer",
                span: #0 bytes(5511..5521),
            },
            Punct {
                ch: ',',
                spacing: Alone,
                span: #0 bytes(5521..5522),
            },
            Ident {
                ident: "Ready",
                span: #0 bytes(5523..5528),
            },
        ],
        span: #0 bytes(5510..5529),
    },
]
```