# How to access custom derive attributes?

Tags: macros, rust

I recently started to experiment with procedural macros on stable. While I understood most parts fairly quickly I did not find a way to actually access custom attributes during my macro.
The only somewhat useful source I found was [this chapter of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/procedural-macros.html).

I am currently stuck with:

```
#[proc_macro_derive(Foo, attributes(Boo, Goo))]
pub fn foo(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // Construct a string representation of the type definition
    let s = input.to_string();

    // Parse the string representation
    let ast = syn::parse_derive_input(&s).unwrap();

    // Build the impl
    let gen = impl_object(&ast);

    // Return the generated impl
    gen.parse().unwrap()
}
```

and

```
#[derive(Foo)]
#[Boo = true]
pub struct Ruu { /* .. */ }
```

How can I use my custom attributes inside of the macro?

Comment: Have you tried looking at my [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484062/how-do-i-process-enum-struct-field-attributes-in-a-procedural-macro/42526546#42526546)?

Comment: While I believe that a question formulated like this is easier to find and more concise and might prevent future duplicates of the same question, both questions most certainly require the same answer. I would love to  write a somewhat generic answer explaining what you can currently do with attributes and current limitations.